# Javascript onmouseover background image change

Tags: javascript, html, image, background, onmouseover

I'm trying to implement this background changer from *removed after edits* to my personal blog that only resides on my computer (not uploading to the internet), but I don't know what the js for it is? How would I go about adding it to my blog? 
I know there's the:

```
<body style="background-image : url();">
```

in the html file later followed by the:

```
<img src="" onmouseover="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url()';" width="20" height="20">
```

Is there anything else besides the js?

Edit: It seems this only works with 12x12 gifs? When I put my own images into the url places, the bg change won't work.

2nd Edit: I found the problem. I had my imgs not named properly.

Comment: These code can implement what you want. No other js are needed. Just change the `url` will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that toggles between two images on the background of a div.

```js
let images = ['https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg','https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg'];
var currentImage = 1;

let myDiv = document.getElementById("myBackground");
myDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) { 
  currentImage = currentImage == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  event.target.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[currentImage]}')`;
});
```

```css
#myBackground {
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg');
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px; solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBackground"></div>
```

Here is a version using just CSS, but limited to mouse over, resets when you leave the element.

```css
    #myBackground {
      background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg');
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px; solid red;
    }
    
    #myBackground:hover {
      background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg');
    }
```

```html
<div id="myBackground"></div>
```

Here is a version the adds a class to the CSS on mouseover.

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myBackground");
myDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) { 
  event.target.classList.add('myOverride');
});
```

```css
        #myBackground {
          background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg');
          height: 300px;
          width: 300px;
          border: 2px; solid red;
        }
        
        #myBackground.myOverride {
          background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg');
        }
```

```html
<div id="myBackground"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work just fine. No need of any other js code.